# sqlite permanently in-memory

Tags: php, sqlite

Is PHP able to handle sqlite data as inmemory DB?

I have a <50MB database and would like a php script to do SELECTs (and if possible also UPDATEs) to the sqlite without slow disk file reading or writing each time, the script is ran.

With java and c++ I know great use-cases, but how to force PHP to access the sqlite inmemory without reloading the file again and again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it:

1. Do nothing, and let the OS cache the database in disk caches / memory buffers. This is good if you have a small database (and <50 MB is small), and if you have lots of memory.
2. Use a `tmpfs` and copy your database file in it, then open it in PHP.
3. Use `sqlite://:memory:` (but you will start from a blank database).

Comment: (3) sounds smart and simple to use for me. but it's not a permanent storage this way

Answer (score 0):

[In memory sql databases](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: That's what I know from java and cpp, but with PHP PDO it looks like it's not a permanent storage (as Artefact2 described).

Comment: I did not read your Q properly, sorry.  I took myself out and gave myself a right good slapping.